# Set- Theoretic Tree property and Model Theory

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory

There is a tree property in set-theory and a tree property in model theory. 
I want the former, not the later.

**Definition**  The tree property holds at some cardinal $\kappa$ if every tree of height $\kappa$ with levels of size less than  $\kappa$ has a cofinal branch.

Counterexamples to the tree property at $\kappa$ are called $\kappa$-Aronszajn trees.

In a few instances, I heard people talking about the tree property as a "compactness property". One of the justifications was the following theorem.

**Theorem** An inaccessible cardinal has the tree property if and only if
it is weakly compact.

Since compactness is a very useful tool in model-theory, one would expect that in the absence of compactness, e.g. in infinitary logics, the tree property to be some sort of replacement. Looking around I did not find anything.

So, my question is:

Do you know any usage of the (set-theoretic) tree property in model theory? Even better, do you know any model-theoretic techniques that use the tree property? By technique, I mean something that can be used in various settings, not in only one particular construction.

Comment: Well, it is equivalent to a weak compactness theorem for $\cal L_{\kappa\kappa}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You mean for $\kappa$ inaccessible?

Comment: Well, the compactness implies inaccessibility. You can find the proof in Kanamori's "The Higher Infinite".

Comment: By the theorem I mentioned, the tree property is equivalent to weak compactness for inaccessible $\kappa$. But how about accessible cardinals, even small cardinals like $\aleph_n$, $n\in\omega$? They consistently satisfy the tree property.

Comment: Correct. But they will not satisfy the weak compactness theorem.

Comment: See Enayat's paper "[Power like models of set theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/div-classtitlepower-like-models-of-set-theorydiv/351DBAD184B5D6CA00C9488CFDF6AB66)"

Comment: Also they are used to get the independence of gap-1 transfer principle.

Comment: @MohammadGolshani: Thank you for your answer. This is the kind of examples I was looking for. I am surprised by how few examples were given.